# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/dynalink/RelinkableCallSite with org.openjdk.nashorn but only on linux with java 17

Tags: java, nashorn, java-17

Just moving to Java 17 from Java 15 and this means the nashorn javascript module is no longer part of Java so I have moved to using https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn instead

Modified code to directly call this script engine

```
ScriptEngine engine = new org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
```

and works fine on Windows, but on Linux Im getting

Getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/dynalink/RelinkableCallSite with org.openjdk.nashorn`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/dynalink/RelinkableCallSite
        at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.<init>(Context.java:655)
        at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.<init>(Context.java:585)
        at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.lambda$new$0(NashornScriptEngine.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.<init>(NashornScriptEngine.java:124)
        at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:152)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.filename.FileNameFormatter.getRenameMaskJavascriptEngine(FileNameFormatter.java:668)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.filename.FileNameFormatter.isAlbumMask(FileNameFormatter.java:752)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.filename.FileNameFormatter.isAlbumMask(FileNameFormatter.java:732)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.init(SongSaver.java:130)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.toplevelanalyzer.FixSongsController.reset(FixSongsController.java:164)
        at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.toplevelanalyzer.FixSongsController.start(FixSongsController.java:185)
        at com.jthink.songkong.ui.swingworker.FixSongs.doInBackground(FixSongs.java:49)
        at com.jthink.songkong.ui.swingworker.FixSongs.doInBackground(FixSongs.java:18)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.dynalink.RelinkableCallSite
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 20 more
```

in both cases using a Java runtime built from Adoptium 17 so I dont see why there is a difference

```
rmdir /S /Q C:\code\jthink\songkong\JVM64
call "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.2.8-hotspot\bin\jlink" --module-path="C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.2.8-hotspot\jmods"  --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.instrument,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec  --output C:\code\jthink\songkong\JVM64
rmdir /S /Q C:\Code\jthink\SongKong\linuxjre
call "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.2.8-hotspot\bin\jlink" --module-path="C:\Code\jthink\SongKong\linux_jdk\jmods"  --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec --output C:\code\jthink\songkong\linuxjre
```

Comment: Try adding the `jdk.dynalink` module to the lists.  According to the JDK 17u source code, the missing class is in that module.

Comment: that was it, git myself confused only work on Windows in dev version but failed as well with my own jre

Comment: You might want to consider adding a module-info to your project as well. Then you could feed your module to jlink and all the dependency modules would be resolved automatically.